# Navigation bar title in Swiftui - iPhoneXR

Tags: ios, swiftui

The navigation bar title is working fine in iPhone 7 plus device but in iphoneXR, the navigation bar title is partially hidden.

[image: SwiftUI in iPhoneXR]

Following is the code used to display this screen. LoginView and ResetView are defined in separate file

```
var body: some View {

    LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(self.isShowLoadingView)) {
        VStack
            {
                if(self.showLoginView)
                {
                    LoginView()
                }
                else if(self.showResetView)
                {
                    ResetView()
                }
                else
                {
                    NavigationView {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading)
                        {
                            Text(EMAIL).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            TextField("", text: self.$emailid)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 45, trailing: 0))
                                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                            Text(PHONE_NUMBER).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            TextField("", text: self.$phoneno)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 45, trailing: 0))
                                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                            Button(action: self.forgotPwdAction) {
                                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(OK_BTN).font(.headline).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(Color.white).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }.padding().background(Color.green)

                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(40)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .navigationBarTitle("Forgot Password")
                            .navigationBarItems(leading: self.btnBack)
                            .navigationBarHidden(false)
                    }
                }
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Set your auto layout constraints to the Safe Area

Comment: I am using swiftui, i don't have storyboard for this

Comment: Show your code..

Comment: remove .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) from your code

Comment: @user3441734, there is white gap in top and bottom of the screen after removing the . edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

Comment: You should at least show a complete example of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that because you have `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` set so the content is flowing into the top safe area?  I would try removing that.

Comment: Yeah, May be he should should change **.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)** to **.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example based on you code snippet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var haha = "placeholder"
    var body: some View {
        VStack
            {
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading)
                {
                    Text("EMAIL").foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    TextField("", text: self.$haha)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 45, trailing: 0))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    TextField("", text: self.$haha)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 45, trailing: 0))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(40)
                .background(Color.black)
                .navigationBarTitle("Forgot Password")
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
            }
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}
```

I added `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])` modifier to the inner `NavigationView`.

It looks like this on iPhone 11 (which has notch too):

[image: preview on iPhone 11]